# tabbing two or one column depending on content length

Tags: tabbing

I have names (random data from outside source), that I want to list in two columns. My problem is, that some of the names are too long to fit in one column, so they should span both columns (they will fit in two columns, I am sure of, so no extra problem here).

Example: (v is the tabbing position) (Michaella is too long for column 2)

```
v        v
Peter    Frank
Barbarella
Dirk     Lisa
Sabrina  
Michaella
```

I have not the slightest idea, which environment to use. So I do not have an MWE.

Comment: You'll be inputting these names manually in some (La)TeX file?

Comment: what is the input order, Peter, Frank, Barbarella, ... or Peter, Barbarella, Dirk, ...

Comment: I generate the tex file. The names are in input order. And all should happen without human tweaking (interference)